# Sum of factorials of 1 to n using only one recursive function

Tags: java, c++, c, recursion, factorial

I need a single recursive function to compute the series `S=1! + 2! + 3! + ...+n!`.

I've done it using 2 functions.

```
void main()
{ 
  int terms=4;
  printf(sum(terms));  //outputs 33
 /* 
    terms is the number of terms in the series
    e.g. terms=3 outputs 9, 4 outputs 33
 */
}

int fac(int n)   
{            
     return n<2 ? 1 : n * fac(n-1) ;
}   
int sum(int terms)   
{     
     return terms>0 ? (fac(terms) + sum(terms-1)):0 ;
}
```

Comment: Do one of the options using a loop?

Comment: You should add a tag with the language you are using.

Comment: @anindya dutta -- no iteration, only recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest I could get it:

```
int sum_fac(int target, int counter) {
    return (target == counter) ? target : counter * (1 + sum_fac(target, counter + 1));
}
```

Which when called like this:

```
int main() {
  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d: %d\n", i, sum_fac(i, 1));
  }
}
```

Outputs this:

```
1: 1
2: 3
3: 9
4: 33
5: 153
6: 873
7: 5913
8: 46233
9: 409113
```

Comment: @user207421 It appears the `target` parameter is provided different values in each iteration of the `for` loop in the `main` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
   sum(1,terms,1,0);
}

int sum (int cur, int terms, int fac, int sumcur) {

    return terms == n? sumcur: sum(cur+1, terms, (cur==1)?1:cur*fac, sumcur+cur*fac);
}
```

Comment: Can't you also statically declare `fact[]` inside of the body of `sum()`, and get rid of the need for external initialization?

Comment: A reason why you should not declare `static` variables inside a function [here](http://www.quora.com/Why-cant-I-declare-a-static-variable-inside-main-method-in-Java).

Comment: Oh, I was thinking C/C++, not Java.

Comment: I removed the array. Edited it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have Something like this :

```
int sumOfFac(int currentNumber, int lastSum, int lastFac, int maxNumber)
{
    int currentFac = currentNmber*lastFac;
    int currentSum = lastSum+currentFac;

    if(currentNumber < maxNumber)
    {
        return sumOfFac(currentNumber+1, currentSum, currentFac, maxNumber);
    }
    return currentSum;
}
```

Then you call that function the first time with :

```
currentNumber = 1
lastSum = 0
lastFac = 1
maxNumber = your n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a_1 = 1!
a_2 = 1!+2!
...
a_n = a_(n-1) + f_(n-1)*n
```

where `f_i = i!`. So basically we need two outputs from the dunction - `a` and `f`. Let's translate it to the code:

```
int series(int n, int *f)
{
    int a, f1;
    if (n < 2)
    {
        *f = 1;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        a = series(n-1, &f1);
        *f = f1 * n;
        return a + (*f);
    }
}
```

And then

```
int main(void) {
    int dummy;
    printf("%d\n", series(1, &dummy));
    printf("%d\n", series(2, &dummy));
    printf("%d\n", series(3, &dummy));
    printf("%d\n", series(4, &dummy));
    return 0;
}
```

prints this:

```
1
3
9
33
```

**Update:** 
 To refactor further, we can say that `f_n = a_n - a_(n-1)`, so  `f_(n-1) = a_(n-1) - a_(n-2)`. Then the recursive case will be:

```
a_n = a_(n-1) + (a_(n-1) - a_(n-2))*n
```

This wont require the calculation of `f`, but need some extra bse cases and extra recursive call:

```
    int series(int n)
    {
        int a1, a2;
        if (n <= 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (n==2)
        {
            return 3;
        }
        else
        {

            a1 = series(n-1);
            a2 = series(n-2);

            return a1 + (a1 - a2)*n;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code using c language

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
  int n;
  printf("Until how many terms?\n");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("The sum of factorials is %d",srs(n));    
  return 0;
}

int factorial(int n){
  return n<2?1:n*factorial(n-1); //(if)?(true):(false)
}

int srs(int n){
  return n>0?( (factorial(n)) + srs(n-1)):0; //(if)?(true):(false)
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.